# SpringBootServletInitializer for multiple services in war for Tomcat

Tags: rest, spring-boot

Spec : SpringBoot 4.x,Tomcat 7.x,JDK1.7

Process : Have 2 Rest Services as in separate package
with unique `@RequestMapping` and deployed as war to tomcat7.x

```
package com.servives.webservice  ~ Service A
package com.servives.dbservive   ~ Service B
package com.initilizer          ~  Service C
```

Problem  :

Service *A works* if the "SpringBootServletInitializer" is present in 
same package , while Service *B does not work*.

Service *B works* if the "SpringBootServletInitializer" is present in 
same package , while Service *A does not work*.

Service *A & B does not work* if "SpringBootServletInitializer" is present in 
separate package 'C'

Question : Is this a Bug or Am i doing some mistake ?

Note: Code sample not sharable for huge dependency.

Comment: can you post your `Appliaction.java` class?

Comment: Package com.initilizer;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
.....
(atrate)SpringBootApplication
public class RestInitlize extends SpringBootServletInitializer { 
(atrate)Override public SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {return application.sources(RestInitlize.class);}
public static void main(String[] args)    {SpringApplication.run(RestInitlize.class, args);}}

(atrate) == @

Comment: Found the issue as in this URL

https://smarterco.de/java-spring-boot-mvc-ontroller-not-called/

SpringBootApplication needs to be replace with 

Configuration
ComponentScan(basePackages = "me.kamwo")
EnableAutoConfiguration

This URL will be sucessfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `@ComponentScan` annotation. You need to add the following to your `Application.java`

```
@ComponentScan({"package.A", "package.B",...})
```

OR 
just add the base package as follows.
 `@ComponentScan("base.package")`